# POST Array to Multiple Variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, checkbox

So on one page I have a little form like this

```
<form method='post' action='trade_confirm.phtml'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='items[]' value='" . $row1["inventory_slot"] . "' />
</form>
```

The form essentially lists multiple checkboxes from a MySQL query, like so:

```
Item #1 (Checkbox)  
Item #2 (Checkbox)  
Item #3 (Checkbox)
```

This is posted to the next page through the _POST["items"] array. I have this on page 2.

```
if (!empty($_POST['items'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['items'] as $selected) {
        echo $selected."</br>";
    }
}
```

The echo command returns the output I want.

```
Item#1
Item#2
Item#3
```

But how can I assign each of these to a variable such as

```
 $variable1 = Item#1;
 $variable1 = Item#2;
 $variable1 = Item#3;
```

(Item#1-3 don't mean anything in the above context. I just don't know what code would go there...)

## EDIT

Another alternative: what is the appropriate way to reference EACH individual item in this post array? Where (And this isn't a syntax-correct example:

```
echo "_POST['items[0]']"
```

This should 9234 to give a blunt example.

The "Items" are integers, not strings.

Comment: Why do you want that? Keep the data in an array! That makes it much easier to handle!

Comment: @deceze Sure. I'll definitely try that. But how do I appropriately reference each individual item in this POST Array?

Comment: By storing them into separate variables. Like : `$item1 = $_POST['item'][0]` and so on. Also if you want the complete set of values of checkboxes, do something like `$data = $_POST['items'][]`

Comment: @Dangling `= $arr[]` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the parts of an array like this

```
echo $_POST['items'][0];
echo $_POST['items'][1];
...
```

Comment: @thomas_lrd
Syntax was a tad off but I know what you mean. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Keep the items in the array. Don't extract them to individual variables, which you're just going to name `$var1`, `$var2` etc. That's pointless. The syntax for accessing an array element is `$arr[0]`, `$arr[1]`; there's no significant advantage to want to replace that with `$var1` instead, the only difference is a `[]`. If you did put all values into individual variables, that'd mean you couldn't *iterate* (loop) over the whole anymore. `foreach ($arr ..)` is simple, `foreach ($var1 ..)` is somewhere between a pain in the neck and impossible.

To answer your direct question:

```
echo $_POST['items'][0];
echo $_POST['items'][1];
...
```